# How to add custom data in http header

Tags: http, http-headers

I want to add some custom data in http header and send it to another web application so I can access that data. How can I do that, please help.

Comment: Could you be more specific on what this *custom data* is?

Comment: data in key, value format like "name=gkk"

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Setting_HTTP_request_headers)

```
// adds "X-Hello: World" header to the request
httpChannel.setRequestHeader("X-Hello", "World", false);
```

Comment: As far as I can see this code only works in a firefox extension.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do is use `java.net.HttpURLConnection.addRequestProperty()` method. E.g

```
httpURLConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", 
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
```

Check [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#addRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for more details.